# How to get summary values from ranked rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, window-functions, summary

Given this data, how can I write SQL to return just one row for each department showing summaries and counts only for ranked rows?

```
with data_row  as
( select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender, 'A' as seqno, 400 as score from dual union all
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 500 as score from dual union all
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender,'C' as seqno, 300 as score from dual union all
  select '345' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'A' as seqno, 600 as score from dual union all
  select '345' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 700 as score from dual union all
  select '222' as emp_id, 'BBB' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'A' as seqno, 200 as score from dual union all
  select '222' as emp_id, 'BBB' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 800 as score from dual  
)
select  dept_id,
        sum(score) over ( partition by dept_id) as rnk_1_sum,
        count(*)   over (partition by dept_id) as dept_count,
        count(*)   over (partition by emp_gender) as male_count,
        count(*)   over (partition by emp_gender) as female_count
   from (  select  emp_id, 
                   dept_id, 
                   seqno, 
                   score,     
                   emp_gender,
  rank() over (partition by emp_id 
                    order by seqno) as rnk
from data_row      
)                
where rnk=1
-- group by dept_id  -- Including this line yields a  ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

**Desired Results**

```
DEPT_ID  RNK_1_SUM DEPT_COUNT MALE_COUNT FEMALE_COUNT
------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------
AAA           1000          2          1            1 /* 123.score  + 345.score = 400 + 600 */
BBB            200          1          0            1 /* 222.score = 200 */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
with data_row  as (
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender, 'A' as seqno, 400 as score from dual union all
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 500 as score from dual union all
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender,'C' as seqno, 300 as score from dual union all
  select '345' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'A' as seqno, 600 as score from dual union all
  select '345' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 700 as score from dual union all
  select '222' as emp_id, 'BBB' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'A' as seqno, 200 as score from dual union all
  select '222' as emp_id, 'BBB' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 800 as score from dual  
)
select  dept_id,
        sum(score) as rnk_1_sum,
        count(*)  as dept_count,
        sum(case when emp_gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male_count,
        sum(case when emp_gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female_count
from data_row      
group by dept_id;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35509) is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

Is this what you want?

```
with data_row  as (
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender, 'A' as seqno, 400 as score from dual union all
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 500 as score from dual union all
  select '123' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'M' as emp_gender,'C' as seqno, 300 as score from dual union all
  select '345' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'A' as seqno, 600 as score from dual union all
  select '345' as emp_id, 'AAA' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 700 as score from dual union all
  select '222' as emp_id, 'BBB' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'A' as seqno, 200 as score from dual union all
  select '222' as emp_id, 'BBB' as dept_id, 'F' as emp_gender,'B' as seqno, 800 as score from dual  
)
select  dept_id,
        sum(score) as rnk_1_sum,
        count(*)  as dept_count,
        sum(case when emp_gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male_count,
        sum(case when emp_gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female_count
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by seqno) as seqnum  
      from data_row    
     ) d
where seqnum = 1
group by dept_id;
```

Comment: Gordon, I'd like to get summary values only for the ranked rows. i.e. Summary and count only for id=123(400 score) + 345(600 score); id=222 has 200, because their ranking by seqno is 1st. When I use partition by to rank my rows, my group by clause at the end causes errors.

Comment: Yes, that's in theory what I want but `group by dept_id` and `partition by ` don't seem to work well for me. In your second query, I get the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error message.

Comment: @zundarz . . . No they don't.  The `group by` was in the wrong place.